# How to parse argv in C (between commas)

Tags: c, bash, command-line-arguments, argv, cmdline-args

I have a little problem with my C program. I would like to parse the args in cmdline into tokens. For example, the program will be running like this: `./hello a b , c , ab c d`  I want to have all letters between commas to be in a variable. So `argv[1]` would be `a b` ; `argv[2]` would be `c` ; `argv[3]` `ab c d`
Is there a way to do it? So that I will be able to play with all token between commas.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to preserve spaces between the letters (as your `a b` example suggests) you do need quotes, as dbush proposes. Bash parses your command line into tokens separated by whitespace before it does anything else, so any unquoted whitespace is only considered as token separator and then discarded.

Comment: Actually no. If you invoke the command in bash exactly as you posted, argv[1] is `a`, argv[2] is `b`, argv[3] is `,`.

Answer (score 3):

Use quotes around the arguments.  Then they'll be treated separately by the shell and passed in as such.

```sh
./hello "a b" "c" "ab c d"
```

Comment: And there’s no way without quotes around the args? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Aquaaa Yes, using quotes is how the shell parses command line arguments, and is the expected way to handle such things.  So `argv[1]` will be `a b`, `argv[2]` will be `c`, and `argv[3]` will be `ab c d`